# Problema con el código de detecciónColisión

Tags: python, pygame

> Estaba creando un código mediante el libro de Inventando con Python en la parte de Pygame y siguiéndolo al pie de la letra (exceptuando las tildes en las palabras), y cuando lo corrí, el código me daba error. Intente usar las sugerencias del programa, pero nada. Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
 
def verifSuperposiciónRects(rect1, rect2):
    for a, b in [(rect1, rect2), (rect2, rect1)]:
        if ((puntoDentroDeRect(a.left, a.top, b)) or
            (puntoDentroDeRect(a.left, a.bottom, b)) or
            (puntoDentroDeRect(a.right, a.top, b)) or
            (puntoDentroDeRect(a.right, a.bottom, b))):
            return True

    return False


def puntoDentroDeRect(x, y, rect):
    if (x > rect.left) and (x < rect.right) and (y > rect.top) and (y < rect.bottom):
        return True
    else:
        return False

pygame.init()
relojPrincipal = pygame.time.Clock()

ANCHOVENTANA = 400
ALTOVENTANA = 400
superficieVentana = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHOVENTANA, ALTOVENTANA), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Deteccion de Colisiones')

ABAJOIZQUIERDA = 1
ABAJODERECHA = 3
ARRIBAIZQUIERDA = 7
ARRIBADERECHA = 9

VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO = 4

NEGRO = (0, 0, 0)
VERDE = (0, 255, 0)
BLANCO = (255, 255, 255)

contadorComida = 0
NUEVACOMIDA = 40
TAMAÑOCOMIDA = 20
rebotin = {'rect':pygame.Rect(300, 100, 50, 50), 'dir':ARRIBAIZQUIERDA}
comidas = []
for i in range(20):
    comidas.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, ANCHOVENTANA - TAMAÑOCOMIDA), random.randint(0, ALTOVENTANA - TAMAÑOCOMIDA), TAMAÑOCOMIDA, TAMAÑOCOMIDA))

while True:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        contadorComida += 1
        if contadorComida >= NUEVACOMIDA:
            contadorComida = 0
            comidas.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, ANCHOVENTANA - TAMAÑOCOMIDA), random.randint(0, ALTOVENTANA - TAMAÑOCOMIDA), TAMAÑOCOMIDA, TAMAÑOCOMIDA))


        superficieVentana.fill(NEGRO)

        if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJOIZQUIERDA:
            rebotin['rect'].left -= VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
            rebotin['rect'].top += VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
        if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJODERECHA:
            rebotin['rect'].left += VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
            rebotin['rect'].top += VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
        if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBAIZQUIERDA:
            rebotin['rect'].left -= VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
            rebotin['rect'].top -= VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
        if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBADERECHA:
            rebotin['rect'].left += VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
            rebotin['rect'].top -= VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO

        if rebotin['rect'].top < 0:
            if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBAIZQUIERDA:
                rebotin['dir'] = ABAJOIZQUIERDA
            if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBADERECHA:
                rebotin['dir'] = ABAJODERECHA
        if rebotin['rect'].bottom > ALTOVENTANA:
            if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJOIZQUIERDA:
                rebotin['dir'] = ARRIBAIZQUIERDA
            if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJODERECHA:
                rebotin['dir'] = ARRIBADERECHA
        if rebotin['rect'].left < 0:
            if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJOIZQUIERDA:
                rebotin['dir'] = ABAJODERECHA
            if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBAIZQUIERDA:
                rebotin['dir'] = ARRIBADERECHA
        if rebotin['rect'].right > ANCHOVENTANA:
            if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJODERECHA:
                rebotin['dir'] = ABAJOIZQUIERDA
            if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBADERECHA:
                rebotin['dir'] = ARRIBAIZQUIERDA

        pygame.draw.rect(superficieVentana, BLANCO, rebotin['rect'])

        for comidas in comidas[:]:
            if verifSuperposiciónRects(rebotin['rect'], comidas):
                comidas.move(comida)

        for i in range(len(comidas)):
            pygame.draw.rect(superficieVentana, VERDE, comidas[i])

        pygame.display.update()
        relojPrincipal.tick(40)
```

> Se supone que durante las últimas líneas de código me sale el error y no sé como solucionarlo. Voy a enlazar el link del libro para que lo vean, es entre las páginas 320 a la 324.

file:///C:/Users/abrah/OneDrive/Documents/Documento%20de%20Abraham%20Pirela.pdf

Comment: No conozco el error, pero en las ultimas lineas, hay un `for comidas in comidas`. En esa parte, reemplazas la lista de comidas por la comida en sí. Entonces, en el siguiente for (`for i in range(len(comidas))`) estás tratando de obtener la cantidad de elementos del ultimo item de la lista comidas. Prueba cambiarle el nombre a la variable en el for, por ejemplo, `for comida in comidas` (sin s), que de hecho deja más claro lo que referencia la variable.

Comment: A simple vista tienes tres errores tipográficos en el código, los tres en el penúltimo `for`. El primero es el que indica y explica muy bien Dante, el segundo es el mismo error pero en el `if` (`comidas` en vez de `comida`) y el tercero es que no es `list.move`, el método que buscas es `list.remove`. Es decir, debería ser     `for comida in comidas[:]:
            if verifSuperposiciónRects(rebotin['rect'], comida):
                comidas.remove(comida)`. (Corrige la identación, en los comentarios se pierde). No veo nada más mal, con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Intente lo que ustedes me dijeron y funcionó. Muchas gracias en serio. Sin embargo, al correrlo, vi que el código estaba lento. Pregunto por qué sería.

Comment: Una cosilla, el enlace que has puesto es de  la localización de un archivo pdf en tu disco duro local. No hay forma de acceder a él, esa URL solo es accesible desde tu ordenador

Comment: Si en el libro no aparecen tildes en las palabras te recomiendo que no decidas ponerlas tú mismo... En programación nunca usamos acentos ni símbolos raros, solemos ceñirnos al abecedario (sin eñe, de hecho) básico digamos. Principalmente por compatibilidad, los símbolos/letras raras (ñ, ç...) no siempre se reconocen bien en todos los equipos.

Answer (score 1):

El primer error y el que te causa el error es el error tipográfico ya comentado:

```
for comidas in comidas[:]:
    |_____|

    if verifSuperposiciónRects(rebotin['rect'], comidas):
                                                |_____|
```

la variable del `for` debe ser `comida` y no `comidas`, esto hace que tras la primera iteración la variable `comidas` deje de hacer referencia a la lista original y haga referencia al primer item de la misma, con los consiguientes errores a continuación por usar la variable `comidas` como si fuera la lista.

El segundo error está en ese mismo ciclo `for`:

```
comidas.move(comida)
```

el método `list.move` no existe, lo que buscas es `list.remove`.

Por último, tienes un problema con esto:

```
while True:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        # Código con el resto de la lógica <<<<<<<<<<<
```

Tienes el código encargado de dibujar cada frame dentro del ciclo encargado de capturar y responder a los eventos de entrada. Esto conlleva que **la aplicación solo se actualiza y genera nuevos frames cuando hay un evento de entrada** (como pulsar una tecla, mover el ratón, etc). Ese código debe ir fuera de este ciclo:

```
while True:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # Código con el resto de la lógica <<<<<<<<<<<
```

El código corregido debería quedar así:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
 
def verifSuperposiciónRects(rect1, rect2):
    for a, b in [(rect1, rect2), (rect2, rect1)]:
        if ((puntoDentroDeRect(a.left, a.top, b)) or
            (puntoDentroDeRect(a.left, a.bottom, b)) or
            (puntoDentroDeRect(a.right, a.top, b)) or
            (puntoDentroDeRect(a.right, a.bottom, b))):
            return True

    return False


def puntoDentroDeRect(x, y, rect):
    if (x > rect.left) and (x < rect.right) and (y > rect.top) and (y < rect.bottom):
        return True
    else:
        return False

pygame.init()
relojPrincipal = pygame.time.Clock()

ANCHOVENTANA = 400
ALTOVENTANA = 400
superficieVentana = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHOVENTANA, ALTOVENTANA), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Deteccion de Colisiones')

ABAJOIZQUIERDA = 1
ABAJODERECHA = 3
ARRIBAIZQUIERDA = 7
ARRIBADERECHA = 9

VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO = 4

NEGRO = (0, 0, 0)
VERDE = (0, 255, 0)
BLANCO = (255, 255, 255)

contadorComida = 0
NUEVACOMIDA = 40
TAMAÑOCOMIDA = 20
rebotin = {'rect':pygame.Rect(300, 100, 50, 50), 'dir':ARRIBAIZQUIERDA}
comidas = []
for i in range(20):
    comidas.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, ANCHOVENTANA - TAMAÑOCOMIDA), random.randint(0, ALTOVENTANA - TAMAÑOCOMIDA), TAMAÑOCOMIDA, TAMAÑOCOMIDA))

while True:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    contadorComida += 1
    if contadorComida >= NUEVACOMIDA:
        contadorComida = 0
        comidas.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, ANCHOVENTANA - TAMAÑOCOMIDA), random.randint(0, ALTOVENTANA - TAMAÑOCOMIDA), TAMAÑOCOMIDA, TAMAÑOCOMIDA))


    superficieVentana.fill(NEGRO)

    if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJOIZQUIERDA:
        rebotin['rect'].left -= VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
        rebotin['rect'].top += VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
    if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJODERECHA:
        rebotin['rect'].left += VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
        rebotin['rect'].top += VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
    if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBAIZQUIERDA:
        rebotin['rect'].left -= VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
        rebotin['rect'].top -= VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
    if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBADERECHA:
        rebotin['rect'].left += VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO
        rebotin['rect'].top -= VELOCIDADMOVIMIENTO

    if rebotin['rect'].top < 0:
        if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBAIZQUIERDA:
            rebotin['dir'] = ABAJOIZQUIERDA
        if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBADERECHA:
            rebotin['dir'] = ABAJODERECHA
    if rebotin['rect'].bottom > ALTOVENTANA:
        if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJOIZQUIERDA:
            rebotin['dir'] = ARRIBAIZQUIERDA
        if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJODERECHA:
            rebotin['dir'] = ARRIBADERECHA
    if rebotin['rect'].left < 0:
        if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJOIZQUIERDA:
            rebotin['dir'] = ABAJODERECHA
        if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBAIZQUIERDA:
            rebotin['dir'] = ARRIBADERECHA
    if rebotin['rect'].right > ANCHOVENTANA:
        if rebotin['dir'] == ABAJODERECHA:
            rebotin['dir'] = ABAJOIZQUIERDA
        if rebotin['dir'] == ARRIBADERECHA:
            rebotin['dir'] = ARRIBAIZQUIERDA

    pygame.draw.rect(superficieVentana, BLANCO, rebotin['rect'])

    for comida in comidas[:]:
        if verifSuperposiciónRects(rebotin['rect'], comida):
            comidas.remove(comida)

    for i in range(len(comidas)):
        pygame.draw.rect(superficieVentana, VERDE, comidas[i])

    pygame.display.update()
    relojPrincipal.tick(40)
```